# EJB3 Entities - Join on Entities in different jar files

Tags: java, ejb-3.0, entity, javabeans

I am trying to do a join on 2 entities using the following query -

```
String qry = "SELECT o.attr1, o.attr2, o.attr3, r.description FROM AttrEntity o,  DescEntity r WHERE (o.code=r.code)";
Query query = entityManager.createQuery(qry);
resultList = query.getResultList();
```

The problem is that the `AttrEntity` and `DescEnity` are in different jar files so when I execute the query I get an exception saying that the entity `DescEntity` was not found. Is there anyway I can execute a this query while not modifying my jar files?

Answer (score 0):

You probably defined a persistence unit in one of those jars (the containing AttrEntity probably). In that persistence unit, you may have listed the classes belonging to that PU. Not sure this is even allowed by the spec, but you may try to change the MANIFEST.MF for the jar containing the PU, adding a "classpath" entry pointing to the other jar containing DescEntity.

But really, if that works, consider it as an UGLY workaround. The proper solution would be to keep them in the same jar.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer - I need to add the tag - secondJar.jar to the persistence.xml of the first jar file.